# Responsive design not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a code I tried but not working especially in mobile view

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="product_body">
    <div class="prod_image">

      <img src="images/product/1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="prod_details">
      <h4>Teddy bear</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 prod_price">
          RS 333

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 prod_offer">
          88% OFF

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Bootstrap is not rocket science! I suggest you read up on how to use bootstrap [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: Can you say what the problem is exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, You need a `<div class="row"` before `col-sm-4`.

EDIT: From your screenshot, I don't see a container, which you will need. Maybe it is already included but I cant see it.
You need to have `<div class="container"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-4">`

Try removing the other divs first to see if that fixes your problem, then work on adding others in.

Comment: Can you give a screen shot?

Comment: the row element used before col-xs-6 goes wild on mobile view , i have a screen shot but dont know how to reply with an image

Comment: please check the image i uploaded now

Comment: There is no image

Comment: the structure of the divs are completely wrong. Let me edit my question

Comment: what i didnt understand